# Using variable in select query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying get count value from a table and storing it in a variable using select statement in stored procedure. But when I use following lines of statemnts

```
DECLARE totalRegister INTEGER;
SET @sqlstmt = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(msisdn)) INTO ', totalRegister, ' FROM    sm_history.svc_mgmt_', @yesterdayMonth,' WHERE action_type = 1 AND DATE(created) = ', yesterday);

PREPARE statement FROM @sqlstmt;
EXECUTE statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
```

I get following error on calling the stored procedure

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1**

I further debugged my stored procedure by using **Select @sql;** and surprised to see it was returning NULL

**Edit 1:** Variables yesterday and yesterdayDate are returning values correctly so I am sure there is no issue with these variables. The problem is due to totalRegister variable

Comment: yesterday is the error ?

Comment: from where `totalRegister`, `@yesterdayMonth` and `yesterday` variable values come? are you sure any of them are not null?

Comment: try to check all of these variables values. Any of them must be null.

Comment: I have already checked yesterdayMonth and yesterday both are returning correct values only totalRegister is causing some prob

Comment: is @yesterdayMonth a table?

Comment: Do you get the expected result when running the query with dummy values?
Try dump @sqlstmt and run the query in your db engine.

Comment: @yestedayMonth is month extracted from yesterday which is date type value

Comment: @usermesam0023 getting error mentioned in the question

Comment: Try INT instead of INTEGER.

Comment: same error nothing different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily I got solution by using hit and trial. Instead of using totalRegister as variable in the CONCAT function replaced it with @totalRegister which caused the stored procedure to work fine.

```
DECLARE totalRegister INTEGER;
SET @sqlstmt = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(msisdn)) INTO @totalRegister FROM sm_history.svc_mgmt_',@yesterdayMonth ,' WHERE action_type = 1 AND DATE(created) = ', "'", yesterday, "'");
PREPARE statement FROM @sqlstmt;
EXECUTE statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
select @totalRegister;
```

Above thing worked fine. Anyways thanks to all for contribution